# Split one column of data, with data from alternate cells in two different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am working on storing data in Excel. I have data in a column like this:

```
Username
 Date
 Swetha
 11/30/2010
 Priya
 11/30/2010
```

[image: SO31372005 question example]

I need above data as below in two columns. Output like this:

```
Username | Date
Swetha   | 11/30/2010  
Priya    | 11/30/2010
```

Thus far I have tried transposing, which is not what I'm looking for.

How might I achieve this result?

Comment: This can be done with the `INDEX` function.

Comment: look into INDEX and ROW. Use INDEX to grab the data from the column with ROW() being used to determine what index to pass to the INDEX function. Something like 2*ROW() or 2*ROW() - 1

Comment: Can you post your final version as answer?  This helps those of us looking for unanswered questions.

Comment: There is also the `TRANSPOSE` function which could be made to work in this instance.  The downside being that it is an array function.  `INDEX` is probably easier.

Comment: username
date
time
status
ShellTerrel
5/25/2010
12:00 PM
For the next hr my tweets devoted to #Edchat Plz join Topic: What is the ideal classroom design for 21st Century Learning?
rliberni
5/25/2010
12:00 PM
Welcome to today's #edchat TopicWhat is the ideal classroom design for 21st Century Learning?

 I have data like this in Excel file in one column and multiple rows,I want first four rows to split into four columns and next respestive data should go their respective columns..I am not able to do all at a time,can you please help me out ?     Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `username` is in A1 copy ColumnA into columnB and in C1 enter:

```
=ISODD(ROW())
```

Fill the formula down (e.g. double-click the fill handle), select the entire sheet, Copy and Paste Special..., Values over the top.

Delete B1 with Shift cell up.

Filter to select `FALSE` (only) in ColumnC. Delete all visible cells except the top row.

Remove filter and delete ColumnC.